# Map MarkerIcon referenced from a different SharePoint view

Tags: sharepoint-online, geolocation, google-maps

Having followed the below blog to get location items in a list on Google Maps I am trying to get my custom markers to show on the map without them being in the default list view. Whilst they're now showing, the map controls appear to be frozen/broken! :/

http://www.incworx.com/diy-custom-sharepoint-series

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location, icon: <a href="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/resourcehub/Lists/Locations/MAP.aspx' 'rows[idx].MarkerIcon'"/a>, content: '<b>'+rows[idx].Title+'</b><br />'+rows[idx].Location+'<br /><br><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i> <b>WiFi: </b>'+rows[idx].WiFi+'<br /><i class="fa fa-print"></i> <b>Printer:  </b>'+rows[idx].Printer+'<br /><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <b>Toilet: </b>'+rows[idx].Toilet+'<br /><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> <b>Refreshments: </b>'+rows[idx].Refreshments+' <br><br><a href="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/resourcehub/Lists/Locations/DispForm.aspx?ID='+rows[idx].ID+'" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:this.href = unescapeProperly(escape(this.href)); (function (url) {var opt = {url: url, autoSize: true, dialogReturnValueCallback: function(res, retVal) { if (res === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) { /*do something useful*/ } }}; SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(opt);})(this.href); return false;">View Details</a>', title: rows[idx++].Title});
```

Answer (score 1):

> SharePoint introduces a new field type named Geolocation that enables you to annotate SharePoint lists with location information. And we can create a map view for the Geolocation field in SharePoint.
>
> For example, you can now make lists "location-aware" and display latitude and longitude coordinates through Bing Maps. An entry is typically seen as a pushpin on a map view(Note: You need to use Bing Maps to achieve this purpose).

Refer to below article for more information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-map-view-for-the-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint